# Kotlin compiles the project properly on local machine but through Jenkins it throws exception

Tags: jenkins, kotlin

I have a library which has a companion object value in it like below

```
companion object {
    const val QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID = "Commands"
}
```

and one class of my project depends on this library uses lib's QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID val like below

```
data class CreateCatalogItemCommand(
    @JsonProperty("styleVariant") val styleVariant: StyleVariant?) : Commandable() {

    companion object {
        const val QUEUE_ID =  QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID.plus("CreateCatalogItemCommand")
    }
}
```

The problem is kotlin compiles the project properly on my machine however via jenkins I get below error. Error disappears when QUEUE_ID set as normal string.

```
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.3.21:compile (compile) @ catalog- 
service ---
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'spring'
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Catalog-Service/src/main/kotlin/com/mg/catalog/command/CreateCatalogItemCommand.kt: (11, 31) Unresolved reference: QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.864s 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 29 08:40:37 UTC 2019
[INFO] Final Memory: 74M/713M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven- 
plugin:1.3.21:compile (compile) on project catalog-service: Compilation 
failure
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Catalog-Service/src/main/kotlin/com/mg/catalog/command/CreateCatalogItemCommand.kt: 
[11,31] Unresolved reference: QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to 
execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.3.21:compile 
(compile) on project catalog-service: Compilation failure
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Catalog-Service/src/main/kotlin/com/mg/catalog/command/CreateCatalogItemCommand.kt:[11,31] Unresolved reference: QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the exception was related to kotlin type inference. After I indicate the type specifically compilation has done without an error. But why? Still don't understand how my machine compiles with type inference?

```
companion object {
    const val QUEUE_CLUSTER_ID: String = "Commands"
}
```